# Using tickboxes to select which class to use

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, concrete5

I am just wondering if there is anyway to make it so that the css class of a DIV can be changed by the selection of a tick box.

For example I have this checkbox HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="size" id="portrait1" value="portrait"> Portrait
<input type="checkbox" name="size" id="landscape1" value="landscape"> Landscape
```

and then this div (used on concrete5 so might make no sense to some)

```
<div class="" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo $form->label('content', t('Title'))
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->text('content')
    ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $al -> file('ccm-b-file', 'fID', t('Choose File'), $bf); ?>
    <?php $bf = File::getByID($fID); ?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $form->label('UserURL', t('URL:'))
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->text('UserURL')
    ?>
</div>
```

but i want it so that when I click portrait, for example, the class of that div changes to say portrait, any way of doing this?

Comment: Changed with what? JavaScript? PHP? Magic?

Comment: @putvande hahah sorry, with PHP would be best! although magic is also a strong contender!

Comment: and because I doubt you want both landscape and portrait checked, maybe radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of JavaScript.

You'll need to bind an event handler to your checkbox (that is, tell the browser to run a chunk of code when a certain event happens: the event in question being changing the state of the checkbox.)

(Note: I am using jQuery in my example for brevity.)

```
$("checkbox#portrait1").bind('change', function() {
    $("div").toggleClass('portrait', $(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

The above example binds the given function to the "change" event of the given selector (`input#portrait1`, i.e. `input` element with the ID of `portrait1`).

When that event happens, it then "toggles" the class `portrait` on the `div` element based on whether the second argument is true or not, meaning if "this" (the checkbox input) is checked, then the class `portrait` will be added to that `div` (if not, remove the class of `portrait`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$('input[name=size]').click(function(){

if($(this).is(':checked'))
  $('div').addClass('test')
else
$('div').removeClass('test')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Always have a default id for div like

```
<div class="" style="display: none;" id="a1">
    <?php echo $form->label('content', t('Title'))
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->text('content')
    ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $al -> file('ccm-b-file', 'fID', t('Choose File'), $bf); ?>
    <?php $bf = File::getByID($fID); ?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $form->label('UserURL', t('URL:'))
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->text('UserURL')
    ?>
</div>
```

and in javascript

```
if(document.getElementById("portrait1").checked == true)
{
document.getElementById("a1").class="portrait";
}
else if(document.getElementById("landscape").checked == true)
{
document.getElementById("a1").class="landscape";
}
```